# linux nc (netcat) UDP Connection refused

Tags: linux, networking, udp, netcat

I faced with some strange `nc` behavior. It works well with TCP when on one host I do:

```
nc -tlp 31337
```

and on the other one:

```
nc 14.0.0.1 31337
```

So there can be some data exchange.
But when I do:

```
nc -ulp 31337
```

then

```
nc 14.0.0.1 31337
```

fails with:

> (UNKNOWN) [14.0.0.1] 31337 (?) : Connection refused

But there are no iptables rules on both listening and connecting sides.

P.S. `nc` version is `v1.10-41`

Comment: Check the manual for the meaning of `-t`. Maybe you though `-t` means TCP. I don't know all `nc` implementations but most likely TCP is specified by *lack* of `-u`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connecting `nc` needs `-u` as well. Otherwise it tries TCP and finds no listening process for this *TCP* port. The last command should be:

```
nc -u 14.0.0.1 31337
```

Comment: curious if there are other reasons for this. Even when specifying `-u` I get `read(net): Connection refused` error on the sending (client) side. Every time.